# c# unity Renewing while loop

Tags: c#, while-loop, unity-game-engine

I have a while loop with a stopper:

```
public Myloop()
{ 
    bool execute == true;
    While (execute == true)
    {
        // do some stuff
        if (condidtion)
        {
            execute == false;
        }    
    }
}
```

and I'm calling in from another function after it stops:

```
Myloop.execute = true;
```

Will this be enough to restart the loop? if not, how can I restart it from another function easy way?

Comment: `bool execute = true;` is how you assign the value.

Comment: once execute is set to false. the loop ends. why not call myLoop again when needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Once a while loop is done it wont start again until you run the `Myloop()` function again:

```
public void RunLoopTwice(){
    MyLoop();
    MyLoop(); 
}

public void Myloop()
{
    bool execute = true;
    while (execute == true)
    {
        // do some stuff
        if (condition)
        {
            execute = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Also normally code is executed in a synchronous order, so only 1 piece of code is executed at the time. with `async/await`, `Task` or `Thread` you can make multiple pieces of code run at once. If you are using any of this, you need to make sure you properly `lock` pieces of code to not get any race conditions.

Answer (score 2):

You are confusing `==` and `=` operators, `==` is for comparison while `=` is for assignment. Read about [C# Operators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d.aspx).

```
public void Myloop()
{
    bool execute = true;
    while (execute == true)
    {
        // do some stuff
        if (condition)
        {
            execute = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Simpler way to do this is using `break` since you are not returning the value of `execute` field. Once the condition is met, `while` loop will terminate.

```
while (true)
{
    // do some stuff
    if (condition) break;
}
```

And you call the method using `Myloop();` not `Myloop.execute = true;`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do with two flags but this code will be run on the different thread because this code will go in the infinite loop.

For Ex.

```
public bool doLoop = true;
public bool doProcess = true;

public void MyLoop()
{
   while(doLoop)
   {
      while(doProcess)
      {
         // do some stuff
         if (condition)
         {
            doProcess = false;
         }
      }
    }
}
```

After your need is completed than make doLoop false